# Mathematica can't solve this ODE system

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equations.But mathematica dosen't work.

```
eq1 = a'[x] - 1/2*a[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*b[x];

eq2 = b'[x] + 1/2*b[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*a[x];

DSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {a[x], b[x]}, x]
```

But it return itself.

````
Out[1] = DSolve[{-(a[x]/2) - 1/2 E^x b[x] + Derivative[1][a][x] == 
   0, -(1/2) E^x a[x] + b[x]/2 + Derivative[1][b][x] == 0}, {a[x], 
  b[x]}, x]

```
````

Comment: That simply means that Mathematica can't find an analytical solution. Add initial conditions and use `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: Maple 2022.2 answers $$\left\{a\! \left(x\right) {=} {\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{2}} \left(\textit{_}\mathit{C1} \mathrm{BesselI}\! \left(0,\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{2}\right)+\textit{_}\mathit{C2} \mathrm{BesselK}\! \left(0,\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{2}\right)\right),
\\
b\! \left(x\right){=}{\mathrm e}^{\frac{x}{2}} \left(\mathrm{BesselI}\! \left(1,\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{2}\right) \textit{_}\mathit{C1}-\mathrm{BesselK}\! \left(1,\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x}}{2}\right) \textit{_}\mathit{C2}\right)\right\} .$$

Comment: Manually elimination of `b[x]` gives a solvable ode

Answer (score 2):

```
Remove[eq1, eq2, solA, A, solB, B, a, b]
eq1 = a'[x] - 1/2*a[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*b[x];
eq2 = b'[x] + 1/2*b[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*a[x];
```

You can do this. Note that each of the expressions has a parameter, but not its derivative. From the second expression get $a[x]$:

```
solA = Solve[eq2 == 0, a[x]]
```

Then substitute this into the first ODE and solve it like one ordinary differential equation for the opposite variable (in this case for `b[x]`):

```
A = a[x] /. solA // First
ReplaceAll[eq1, {a[x] -> A, a'[x] -> D[A, x]}]
solB = DSolve[% == 0, b[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

Then substitute into the first equation and get a couple of solutions $A,B$:

```
B = ReplaceAll[A, {solB[[1]] // First, D[solB[[1]] // First, x]}] // FullSimplify
```

The same is done and vice versa.

```
Remove[eq1, eq2, solA, A, solB, B, a, b]
eq1 = a'[x] - 1/2*a[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*b[x];
eq2 = b'[x] + 1/2*b[x] - 1/2*Exp[x]*a[x];
```

From the first expression get $b[x]$:

```
solB = Solve[eq1 == 0, b[x]]
```

hen substitute this into the second ODE and solve it like one ordinary differential equation for the opposite variable (in this case for `a[x]`):

```
B = b[x] /. solB // First

ReplaceAll[eq2, {b[x] -> B, b'[x] -> D[B, x]}]

solA = DSolve[% == 0, a[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

Then substitute into the second equation and get a couple of solutions $A,B$:

```
A = ReplaceAll[B, {solA[[1]] // First, D[solA[[1]] // First, x]}] // FullSimplify
```

The most interesting thing is that such a naive approach gives, perhaps, two pairs of solutions separately. In the figure below, the solution plots for each of the cases are symmetrical about the x-axis.

[image]